# Existence of a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is some arc $[a,c]$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is homeomorphic to [0,1]). I hope the abuse of notation is no problem
   here, but to me it is easier to write arcs like writing intervalls. Furthermore lets consider a closed disk, call it D, around this arc with the endpoint $c$ lying on the boundary of $D$. Now I want to define a 
   homeomorphism $f:D \to D$ such that the arc $[a,b] \subset [a,c]$ maps to the whole arc. That the little part of the arc is homeomorphic to the whole arc is clear
   to me (per definition), but how to extend this homeomorphism to the whole disk such that on top of that it is the identity-map on the boundary $\partial D$? I guess one could use
   some partition of unity here, but to be honest, I'm not sure how to apply it correctly.

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: The differential topology approach is to do this continuously - using flows of vector fields we can construct a family of diffeomorphisms interpolating between the identity and the desired one. In particular you should look up the *isotopy extension theorem* - it will do most of the hard work for you here.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I looked it up in Milnors Lectures on the h-Cobordism ("http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/hcobord.pdf") but according to this theorem my homeomorphism must be isotopic to the inclusion... are there other ways appart from the smooth category to do such extensions?

Comment: The obvious homeomorphism $[a,b] \to [a,c]$ (just scaling up) is isotopic to the identity - just linearly interpolate. I don't have much experience working with just topological manifolds, so I can't suggest a different approach, sorry.

Comment: Oh, yes!!! And ... thanks anyway!

Comment: It is unclear what category you are working with: Your question suggests the topological category, while your response to Anthony's suggestion indicates that you are interested in the smooth category. In the topological category the answer is positive, provided that you word your question more carefully, say, assume that $int(D)$ contains $[a,c]$ (otherwise, the answer is clearly negative). And a proof is much different from the one Anthony suggested (as the claim fails for topological arcs in 3-balls).

Comment: I'm definitely interested in the pure topological category! My function $f$ is a homeomorphism, NOT smooth. Unfortunately I would like to have that the endpoint "c" from the arc [a,c] lies on the boundary of the disk. You mentioned that then there is no homeo. which fixes $c$, streches the little [a,b] to [a,c] and is the identity on the boundary of $D$. Why is that so?

Comment: Ok let us assume the arc completely lies in the interior of D. How would we do it topologically?

Answer (score 0):

For all those who have questions that are similar to this one. To do it topologically one can use the **Schoenflies theorem** twice! Then the result immediately follows and it does not matter if the arc lies in the interior of the disk.